# Focusrite Scarlett 18i6 - No output in FL Studio

Tags: fl-studio

I am using Focusrite scarlett 18i6 with FL studio. I can see the input and output meter in the mixer are active, but I cannot hear any sound in my speaker. How do I map the output to speaker?

Beginner here, any help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried checking the master gain knob on the scarlett?

Comment: I answered a [question here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/do-audio-interfaces-output-sounds-from-my-computer-or-only-from-the-input-device/4777#4777) with a lot of info about drivers and audio interface setups that might help too

Comment: Do You have any other open applications that are using ASIO sound.  For the most part, only one application can use the ASIO drivers at one time.  The application opened first will almost certainly have priority.

Answer (score 0):

Inside FL Studio, hit F10 to open options.

1. Enable the scarlett audio interface.
2. Make sure volume is turned up a bit.
3. Try the MIX KNOB.  Make sure it's turned to the right.
4. Go to the audio settings, it looks like a speaker, and turn from Primary Driver, to the Focusrite option.

If these do not work, make sure you have installed your drivers from http://global.focusrite.com/downloads !!